# ListView is invisible in Activity

Tags: android

I've a one `ListView` as shown below, when the program is first executed,then it is visible
later automatically invisible.

This layout is visible when User clicks the `Button`, before that the `Visibility` is `GONE`

```
    <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/comments_block"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/header"
     android:visibility="gone" >
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/comments_subHeadding"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:text="Type your comment"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="@color/red" />
     <EditText
     android:id="@+id/user_commetns"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dip"
     android:layout_below="@+id/comments_subHeadding"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:imeOptions="actionSend"
     android:inputType="textLongMessage" />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

This Layout contains `ListView` Here I'm facing the problem.

```
     <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/listview_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/comments_block"
     android:background="@color/ios_blue"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <ListView
     android:id="@+id/comments_list1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
     </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Code**

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
    if (v == add_comment_button) 
    { 
        if(show)
        { 
             comments_block.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
             show = false; 
             return; 
        } 
        else
        { 
            comments_block.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            show = true; 
        } 
    } 
    else if (v == back_comments_button) 
    { finish(); } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post you activity?

Comment: paste your code,so that we can figure out the issue

Comment: try using `invisible` instead of  `gone`. I think that `gone` means that you do not want to see it at all.

Comment: @Cedric Simon,if gone,then our aim is reached,else nothing.And I put Visibility is for ListView only.

Comment: Your `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`, is it possible that your `ListView` is empty and therefore it has no height?

Comment: I'm still confused on what the problem is. The `layout` for your `ListView` is `GONE` initially then set to `VISIBLE` with a `Button`. So where is the problem?

Comment: OKay,I try to add the code.

Comment: @CedricSimon they both mean that the `View` isn't shown. The difference is that `Visible` will still draw the space where it would be but `GONE` will free up that space for other `Views`

Comment: @codeMagic,no not at all,ListView's visibility is VISIBLE only,the above layout is on/off.

Comment: You just remove your background and run your program it will work fine...All the best

Comment: @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (v == add_comment_button) {
   if(show){
    comments_block.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    show = false;
    return;
   }
   else{
    comments_block.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    show = true;
   }
  } else if (v == back_comments_button) {
   finish();
  }

 }

Comment: @NaveenKumar,I did that also,no use.So I posted my java code also,plz check it out.

Comment: Please will you able to put your full activity code

Comment: if(v==R.id.add_comment_button) You just compare like this it's a problem i think..

Comment: @nKn,1st time I gave the values directly in XML file,even though I've same issue

Comment: @codeMagic,okay,I'l try,Thanq

Comment: @codeMagic,ok,we'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for your problem.....
You are just **showing and hiding the comments_block only**....
you try this one...I hope it will help you definitely...All the bset

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
if (v == add_comment_button) 
{ 
    if(show)
    { 
         comments_block.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
         listview_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
         show = false; 
         return; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        comments_block.setVisibility(View.GONE);             
        listview_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        show = true; 
    } 
} 
else if (v == back_comments_button) 
{ finish(); } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are doing 
 `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, if there are no item in listview then its height will be 0.

So please if you will use `match_parent` instead of  `wrap_content`

```
android:layout_height="match_content" 

android:layout_weight="1"
```

Then your listview will be visible.

I hope it will work.

Comment: ,1st time I gave the values in declaration of the LISTVIEW,but I've same problem